# ASP.NET Core 2.2 deleted user is Authorized

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-identity

I am using Razor pages with Core Identity - all models are marked by [Authorize] attribute.

On two (different) Web browsers I have logged users.

One of them is deleting the other one - and then the deleted user is still Authorized!

I've tried removing user directly from DB and:

```
await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
```

and still

```
SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)
```

returns true and AuthorizeAttribute allows to reach the page model.

Any idea how to prevent authorizing deleted user?

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a user, their security stamp is also deleted. However, the security stamp is only evaluated every so often.

The user will be prompted to sign back in the after their security stamp is next re-evaluated, as determined by the `SecurityStampValidationInterval`. By default, security stamps are re-evaluated every 30 minutes.

If you need to ensure they are signed out immediately after a user is deleted, then you can set the `SecurityStampValidationInterval` timespan to zero, in *Startup.cs*. This will make it so that the security stamp is re-evaluated for every request.

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // enables immediate logout, after updating the user's security stamp.
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;   
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.identityoptions.securitystampvalidationinterval?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Answer (score 0):

The method checks if the user is authenticated in the browser by his cookie identity, which is still set after you deleted the user.
You can take a look [here at the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.issignedin?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_IsSignedIn_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsPrincipal_). My approach would be to remove the cookie after the user got deleted or sign the user with the [`SignOutAsync` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.signoutasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_SignInManager_1_SignOutAsync).

You can take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1#methods) at the official documentation. There you find more properties, methods and so on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I don't think it's possible to remove cookie from another browser :/

Comment: No problem. You can remove the cookie inderectly be signign the user out after you deleted him.

Comment: Sadly SignInManager.SignOutAsync is signing out only currently logged user,

let me explain again -> From one computer I am deleting user from database while he is logged in currently on the other computer. [Authorize] still gives authorization but the user is not existing in the database.

How can I signout user from another web browser?

Comment: Add this to your question, this was unclear for me and could also be for others. You could check at the other browser if the user still exists and then call the signout method if the user doesn't exists in the db any more

Comment: Cant you get the user from the database sign the user out and the delete it.